# What does this symbol on PCB mean?

Tags: pcb, symbol

[image]

I've searched for this symbol for hours but can't find what this means..

Comment: Context? What kind of PCB? Is there an LCD screen or some sort of display?

Comment: It's on a LED module

Comment: It's the international symbol for "Humpty Dumpty"

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what it's doing on a circuit board, but I've see that symbol on lamps.

It means "if you break the glass window, replace it with a new one."

I've generally seen it on 230VAC, 500 watt halogen flood lights that have a tube light emitter behind a thin glass panel.  The light will work fine without the glass panel, but is a safety hazard because the halogen bulb can get very hot and because there are terminals exposed that carry 230VAC.

Maybe your LED module PCB is intended to operate on mains voltage, and the warning is there to remind you not to operate the lamp if the cover is broken.